# How to customize only with css for html5 input range slider-vertical?

Tags: css, html, input, slider, range

I would like to customize the look of a html5 input[range] when it's vertical.

**Want to avoid CSS 3 directive like transform:rotate**, it complicates the UI layout then.

Webkit css properties are recognised in my context, the others vendors are useless in my case.

The customisation works good for the horizontal default slider, but not for the vertical one, you can look at here :

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/QU5VD/1/

Otherwise, here's the code :

**HTML**

`<input type="range" class="vHorizon" />`

`<input type="range" class="vVertical" />`

**CSS**

```
input[type="range"].vHorizon {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   background-color: pink;
   width: 200px;
   height:10px;
}
input[type="range"].vVertical {
   -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
   background-color: pink;
   width: 10px;
   height:200px;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   background-color: red;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: a trick that I know is to use `transform: rotate(90)` on horizontal one. But its a dirty trick and I won't advice to use it. But still its good to know it.

Comment: Thks, yes for several reasons, it's not a such good trick (have to care position, it makes CPU work (embedded software))

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue and I'm wondering if anyone have found a better solution for this.
Using rotations brings the slider positioning totally out of control :(

Comment: Also have the same problem with the transform:rotate. the positionning changes according to the browser

Answer (score 7):

******UPDATED ANSWER****

If i understand you correctly, you are trying to make you vertical look like what your horizontal looks like? if so:

```
    input[type=range].vVertical {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: green;
    width: 200px;
    height:10px;

      -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);       
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    z-index: 0;
}
input[type=range].vHorizon {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: pink;
    height: 10px;
    width:200px;

}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QU5VD/9/) <--**UPDATED**

Comment: Your trick works, but like I said and I should have asked in my question, I would like to avoid css transform workaround. It brings position and other' issues